# How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

my problem is that when I set a for loop to look through a list it doesn't work because it is out of range, even when I start at 0.

I have tried changing the range of the for loop but is isn't working.

```
Code = input("Enter your Key code: ")

Code = list(Code)

message = input("Enter your message: ")

message = list(message)

for i in (0, len(message)):
    if message[i] == Code[0]:
        message[i] = 'a'
```

I thought that it would work but it at the start of the for loop it breaks down.

Comment: you *probably* meant to have `for i in range(len(message))`. As you have it, you're iterating over a tuple with 2 elements. The second element is the `len(messages)` which is out of bounds for your list.

Comment: My answer should solve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in (0, len(message)):
```

Should probably be

```
for i in range(len(message)):
```

You forgot the `range`

Answer (score 0):

You want to do:

```
for i in range(len(message)):
    ...
```

`(0, len(message))` is a tuple. Iterating over this will give you `0`, then `len(message)` (which will always be 1 larger than the biggest valid index in your list), hence causing an IndexError.

You also probably want to check that `Code` has at least 1 character in it, otherwise `Code[0]` will also give you an IndexError.

```
Code = list(Code) or '?'
```

will set `Code` to `'?'` if `Code == ''`.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo

it should be like this:

for i in range(len(message))

Your for loop is turple so it will always start from 1+ of what u want